# Toggle between radio button in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, radio-button

Hi I am new to Lightning and working on radio buttons. However I am unable to find any documentation on how to toggle between the two buttons. My requirement is that either of the buttons needs to be selected.

```
<div class="slds-tabs__content slds-show" role="tabpanel">
<div class="slds-media">
<div class="slds-media__body tab-top-panel">
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-space">
<div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1">
<div class="top-panel-button-wraper">
<a class="slds-button slds-button--brand top-panel-button flat-blue" >
<div class="uiInput uiInputRadio uiInput--default uiInput--radio">
   <label class="uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel" for="globalId"><span>Driver REport</span></label>
   <input type="radio" id="globalId">
   </input>
</div>
<div class="uiInput uiInputRadio uiInput--default uiInput--radio">
   <label class="uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel" for="globalId"><span>Volume Report</span></label>
   <input type="radio" id="globalId">
   </input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitesh's [Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/120162/29501) is correct.
You need to provide the same name for all radio buttons.

If you want to preselect a radio input,
you have to provide `checked=""` or `checked="checked"`

See https://jsfiddle.net/dLvu9av6/ for clarification

Answer (score 1):

For Radio button you need to Simply give them the same name.

```
<input type="radio" id="globalId" name="reportRadio">
```

Comment: I was asking about how to set default to one radio button and toggle when the other is selected . Any insight into that?

Comment: then use <input type="radio" id="globalId" name="reportRadio"{!IF((condition),'checked="checked"', '')} />